# How to persist a tab that is opened via `gnome-terminal --tab` after closing process

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I currently have a .sh script that opens 3 new tabs for me and runs a task inside that terminal window:

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=/home/hutber/site/refdata_service --tab -e "yarn start:dev" --title "RefData!"
```

However, when I am inside this tab and exit out of the process with `cntrl+c` the tab closes and I need to manually go a start the process again.

I would like these tabs to stay open once I close the task.

`v3.28.2`

Comment: I liked this solution better, which has one create a very basic shell script and run that with `gnome-terminal`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4466083/1599699